# How to split a single row into multiple rows using SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, rows

My T-SQL code selects information concerning college debt amounts from a table. The code itself works, but I need to break the single row up. There are 4 rows, one for each debt level. I'm probably missing something simple at this point.

```
USE [College Database]
GO


DECLARE @P10W FLOAT, @P25W FLOAT, @P75W FLOAT, @P90W FLOAT, @P10A FLOAT, @P25A FLOAT, @P75A FLOAT, @P90A FLOAT

SELECT  @P10W = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,0),SUM(CUML_DEBT_P10*CUML_DEBT_N)/SUM(CUML_DEBT_N)),
@P25W = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,0),SUM(CUML_DEBT_P25*CUML_DEBT_N)/SUM(CUML_DEBT_N)),
@P75W = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,0),SUM(CUML_DEBT_P75*CUML_DEBT_N)/SUM(CUML_DEBT_N)),
@P90W = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,0),SUM(CUML_DEBT_P90*CUML_DEBT_N)/SUM(CUML_DEBT_N))
FROM CollegeInfo

SELECT 
@P10A = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,0),AVG(CUML_DEBT_P10)),
@P25A = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,0),AVG(CUML_DEBT_P25)),
@P75A = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,0),AVG(CUML_DEBT_P75)),
@P90A = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,0),AVG(CUML_DEBT_P90))
From CollegeInfo

SELECT  '10%  Debt Level', 
CUML_DEBT_P10 AS 'Institution',
@P10A AS 'Average',
@P10W AS ' Weighted Average' ,
'25%  Debt Level', 
 CUML_DEBT_P25 AS 'Institution',
 @P25A AS 'Average',
 @P25W AS ' Weighted Average' ,  
 '75%  Debt Level', 
 CUML_DEBT_P75 AS 'Institution',
 @P75A AS 'Average',
 @P75W AS ' Weighted Average' ,
 '90%  Debt Level', 
 CUML_DEBT_P90 AS 'Institution',
 @P90A AS 'Average',
 @P90W AS ' Weighted Average' 
 FROM CollegeInfo
 WHERE INSTNM LIKE'%Alabama A & M%'
```

Right now it reads as

```
10%  Debt Level 4750    3530    2816    25%  Debt Level 9500    6243    5990    75%  Debt Level 37900   18543   27976   90%  Debt Level 50114   25147   39153
```

But it needs to read as

```
10%  Debt Level 4750    3530    2816    
25%  Debt Level 9500    6243    5990    
75%  Debt Level 37900   18543   27976   
90%  Debt Level 50114   25147   39153
```

Comment: Use 4 select statements and `UNION ALL`  Looks like you may need to put a LoanType  since the amounts would be on separate rows.

Comment: How exactly would I modify the code to use UNION ALL?

The row information is where it says "xx%  Debt Level',"

Comment: I think the unions would work but there may be a better way w/o all the user variables.  Just need to think about it.  The issue is you have a 1:M relationship within collegeInfo in the fact that the you have multiple columns for a level.  Had this been normalized you'd have 4 rows instead of 4 columns; thus I think the union all approach is appropriate.  I considered a cross join to a table w/ 4 values and using max and group by but I wasn't sure what that would do to your totals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT '10%  Debt Level'
     , CUML_DEBT_P10 AS 'Institution'
     , @P10A AS 'Average'
     , @P10W AS ' Weighted Average'
FROM CollegeInfo
WHERE INSTNM LIKE'%Alabama A & M%'

UNION ALL
SELECT'25%  Debt Level', 
     , CUML_DEBT_P25 AS 'Institution'
     , @P25A AS 'Average'
     , @P25W AS ' Weighted Average'
FROM CollegeInfo
WHERE INSTNM LIKE'%Alabama A & M%'

UNION ALL
SELECT '75%  Debt Level'
     , CUML_DEBT_P75 AS 'Institution'
     , @P75A AS 'Average'
     , @P75W AS ' Weighted Average' 
FROM CollegeInfo
WHERE INSTNM LIKE'%Alabama A & M%'

UNION ALL
SELECT '90%  Debt Level'
     , CUML_DEBT_P90 AS 'Institution'
     , @P90A AS 'Average'
     , @P90W AS ' Weighted Average' 
FROM CollegeInfo
WHERE INSTNM LIKE'%Alabama A & M%'
```

I suppose you could do this as well:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  '10%  Debt Level' debtLevel, 
CUML_DEBT_P10 AS 'InstitutionA',
@P10A AS 'AverageA',
@P10W AS [Weighted AverageA] ,
'25%  Debt Level', 
 CUML_DEBT_P25 AS 'InstitutionB',
 @P25A AS 'AverageB',
 @P25W AS [Weighted AverageB] ,  
 '75%  Debt Level', 
 CUML_DEBT_P75 AS 'InstitutionC',
 @P75A AS 'AverageC',
 @P75W AS [Weighted AverageC] ,
 '90%  Debt Level', 
 CUML_DEBT_P90 AS 'InstitutionD',
 @P90A AS 'AverageD',
 @P90W AS [Weighted AverageD] 
 FROM CollegeInfo
 WHERE INSTNM LIKE'%Alabama A & M%')

SELECT B.DL
     , max(CASE WHEN B.DL='10%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.InstitutionA
                WHEN B.DL='25%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.InstitutionB
                WHEN B.DL='75%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.InstitutionC
                WHEN B.DL='90%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.InstitutionD END) as Institution
     , max(CASE WHEN B.DL='10%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.AverageA
                WHEN B.DL='25%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.AverageB
                WHEN B.DL='75%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.AverageC
                WHEN B.DL='90%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.AverageD END) as Average
     , max(CASE WHEN B.DL='10%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.[Weighted AverageA]
                WHEN B.DL='25%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.[Weighted AverageB]
                WHEN B.DL='75%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.[Weighted AverageC]
                WHEN B.DL='90%  Debt Level' THEN CTE.[Weighted AverageD] END) as WeightedAverage 
FROM CTE
CROSS JOIN (SELECT '10%  Debt Level' DL UNION ALL 
            SELECT '25%  Debt Level' UNION ALL
            SELECT '75%  Debt Level' UNION ALL
            SELECT '90%  Debt Level') B
GROUP BY B.DL
```

Comment: Thanks that helped out now I just have to get the cursor section working as well.

Comment: Oi... RDBMS work best when processing in sets not record by record.  cursors are needed about 5% of the time.  the rest of the time set based processes work better.  your case may be in that 5% but 95% of the time it could be done in sets :P